# Advantages of compressed data in socket

Tags: c++, sockets, zlib

I'm using **zlib** to compress my files and i not see a significant change in its size after compression, i'm trying to have an improvement in transfer speed with socket, so i'm trying to compress files before sending it over socket.

I am using the following code to compress files:

```
int compress_file(char *infilename, char *outfilename) {
        FILE *infile = fopen(infilename, "rb");
        gzFile outfile = gzopen(outfilename, "wb");
        if (!infile || !outfile) return -1;

        char inbuffer[128];
        int num_read = 0;
        unsigned long total_read = 0, total_wrote = 0;
        while ((num_read = fread(inbuffer, 1, sizeof(inbuffer), infile)) > 0) {
            total_read += num_read;
            gzwrite(outfile, inbuffer, num_read);
        }
        fclose(infile);
        gzclose(outfile);
}
```

What are the advantages of compressing a file before sending on socket?

Comment: Why are you compressing the file **before** sending it over the socket?  You should compress it **while** sending it.  Then you don't have to waste any time pre-compressing the file, and don't have to waste any temp disk space.

Comment: What kind of files are you compressing?  Remember that if the file is already well-compressed (e.g. a .zip file or a .mp3 file) then compressing it further probably won't get you much additional size reduction (and might in fact even make the file-size larger!)

Comment: compress each chunk of file while send ? I can compress these bytes with zlib?

Comment: @RemyLebeau perhaps in the exploratory stages, compressing if before is better: this way, one can assess the compression ratio and ask SO for a better streaming compression algo before jumping into one blindly?

Comment: @Melissia_M: The point Remy's making is that you're taking a file, reading that file and writing a compressed file, then reading the compressed file into memory and sending it. The compressed file itself is pointless; you should compress it *into memory*, not into a file.

Comment: @Melissia_M: After you read a chunk of data into your `inbuffer`, you can use the zlib library to compress it to another memory buffer instead of writing it to a file. Then you can send that compressed buffer over the socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i liked this logic, now is studying a way to do it with zlib, i have to unpack each chunk of file received on the server side... if I can not, I'll make another question

Answer (score 1):

> What are the advantages of compressing a file before sending on socket?

Evidently, saving network bandwidth. However, this will be a trade-off. So the following will just touch the **dis**advantages

Hard to choose a sweet-spot in network compression, especially when the content to be compressed is unknown.

You need to balance between 'speed of compression' vs 'compression rate' vs 'speed of decompression':

1. if first is low, you have unused network capacity while you are compressing the payload
2. if compression ratio is low, then you *may* end with network "saturation" if there are heaps of clients communicating and/or your available bandwidth is narrow
3. if the speed of decompression is low, you may swamp the server CPU in doing mostly decompression instead of processing the payload.

In any case, using compression in networking doesn't come for free: it is a trade-off between network bandwidth and CPU-cycles on both ends. If you add SSL/TSL on top of your compression, you may finish in a prohibitive CPU cost *especially on the server/master-side* (scale your cluster, arrange for extra cooling, do load balancing, hire guru sysadms, etc. Isn't it cheaper to just take a larger tube for those incoming bits)?

For the most usual scenarios, when the compression is justified, the balance is shifted with the heavier side on the client - it is supposed the clients will have excess processing capacity so picking a better compression algo will save bandwidth and server CPU.

However, the situation changes when the sender is under 'real-time pressure' (think live-streaming a concert, or collecting data from colliding Higgs bosons-and-whatnot at LHC in Geneva): if compression is used (most of the time it won't, with the exception of the compression algos built in the standards/codecs), the compression ratio will be low and computational cheap.